# How can I rearrange my listview layout in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, scrollbar

This is my current layout for my listview

[image]

How can I display the flag on the left, move the word to the right, and place country as the first row, followed by rank and population?

And, how can I add a scrollbar on the side, so that it can slide down to see all the countries?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ranklabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ranklabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rank"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ranklabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countrylabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ranklabel"
        android:text="@string/countrylabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rank"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/countrylabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/populationlabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/countrylabel"
        android:text="@string/populationlabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/population"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/country"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/populationlabel" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="22px"
        android:layout_height="22px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:src="@drawable/"Your Image" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ranklabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ranklabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rank"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ranklabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countrylabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ranklabel"
        android:text="@string/countrylabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rank"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/countrylabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/populationlabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/countrylabel"
        android:text="@string/populationlabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/population"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/country"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/populationlabel" />
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I display the flag on the left, and move the Word to the
>   right? And place country as the first row, follow by rank and
>   Population?

=> I assume you knows everything about RelativeLayout so I would suggest you to try yourself some attributes like:

```
android:layout_below
android:layout_toRightOf
```

> How can I add a scrollbar on the side, so that it can slide down to
>   see all the country?

=> As ListView is itself a scrollable view, you don't need to use `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ranklabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/flag"
        android:text="RANK" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rank"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text=" 1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ranklabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countrylabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ranklabel"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/flag"
        android:text="COUNTRY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" England"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rank"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/countrylabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/populationlabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/countrylabel"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/flag"
        android:text="POPULATION" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/population"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text=" 200 00"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/country"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/populationlabel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your relative layout make your imageView as first child and apply `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/flag"` in each of your lables

Or just copy and paste the following code in your XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ranklabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flag"
        android:text="@string/ranklabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rank"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ranklabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countrylabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ranklabel"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flag"
        android:text="@string/countrylabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rank"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/countrylabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/populationlabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flag"
         android:layout_below="@+id/countrylabel"
        android:text="@string/populationlabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/population"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/country"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/populationlabel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```